# kivy layout: different computer different display

Tags: python, layout, kivy

The same code for python layout returns different GUI. I'm terribly confused:

```
# ---------- VQCIA.kv  ----------

VQCIA:

<VQCIA>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    goi: goi
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    size: 400, 200
    pos: 200, 200
    size_hint:None,None

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Enter gene of interest with TAIR ID:"
            font_size: '25sp'

    BoxLayout: 
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'AT3G20770'
            multiline: False
            font_size: '25sp'
            id: goi

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.submit_goi()

# ---------- vqcia.py  ----------

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty 

class VQCIA(BoxLayout):

    # Connects the value in the TextInput widget to these
    # fields
    goi = ObjectProperty()

    def submit_goi(self):

        # Get the student name from the TextInputs
        goi = self.goi.text
        print goi
        return


class VQCIAApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VQCIA()


dbApp = VQCIAApp()
dbApp.run()
```

my lab computer is macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with Kivy==1.10.1 and has ideal output:
[image: Img01 - macOS Sierra 10.12.6]

on the other side my personal mac, macOS high Sierra 10.13.6 with Kivy==1.10.1, has wrong outputs:
[image: Img02 - macOS high Sierra 10.13.6]

what happens?

Comment: You understand that it is uncomfortable to receive check and uncheck every so often, I consider it noise and it takes away the desire to help you, avoid being noisy.

Comment: sorry for that. I'm new to use stack overflow. I thought it i could accept multiple answers, but then i realize that once i accept one answer it cancel the other one. sorry for that again.

Comment: If you have another question do not do it in the comments section, they only serve to discuss the current question, if you have another question create a new POST, if you do not want to cause more problems, read [ask] and pass the [tour]

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. sorry for bad operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using Density-independent Pixels, `dp`.
2. In kv file, there are two roots. There is a root rule, `VQCIA:` and also a class rule, `<VQCIA>:` for the root. Since in Python code, it is using `return VQCIA()`, which is associated to class rule, `<VQCIA>:` in kv file. Therefore, remove root rule, `VQCIA:` to avoid confusion.

## kv file - vqcia.kv

```
<VQCIA>:    # class rule for root widget
    orientation: "vertical"
    goi: goi
    padding: dp(10)
    spacing: dp(10)
    size: dp(400), dp(200)
    pos: dp(200), dp(200)
    size_hint: None, None
```

[Dimensions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions)

> ```
> dp
> ```
>
> Density-independent Pixels - An abstract unit that is based on the
>   physical density of the screen. With a density of 1, 1dp is equal to
>   1px. When running on a higher density screen, the number of pixels
>   used to draw 1dp is scaled up a factor appropriate to the screen’s
>   dpi, and the inverse for a lower dpi. The ratio of dp-to-pixels will
>   change with the screen density, but not necessarily in direct
>   proportion. Using the dp unit is a simple solution to making the view
>   dimensions in your layout resize properly for different screen
>   densities. In others words, it provides consistency for the real-world
>   size of your UI across different devices.
>
> ```
> sp
> ```
>
> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also
>   scaled by the user’s font size preference. We recommend you use this
>   unit when specifying font sizes, so the font size will be adjusted to
>   both the screen density and the user’s preference.